# Log4j2: toString() called instead of formatTo() on StringBuilderFormattable

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, stringbuilder

I am using log4j2 version 2.10.0

I have implemented `StringBuilderFormattable` interface to make gc-free logging.

Example implementation:

```
    public static class Formattable implements StringBuilderFormattable {


    @Override
    public void formatTo(StringBuilder buffer) {
        buffer.append("FORMAT_TO_CALLED");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TO_STRING_CALLED";
    }
}
```

I am calling `LOGGER.info(new Formattable());`
And getting  `TO_STRING_CALLED` instead of expected `FORMAT_TO_CALLED`.

I am currently running it with such properties:

```
-Dlog4j2.enable.threadlocals=true
-Dlog4j2.enable.direct.encoders=true
-Dlog4j2.asyncLoggerWaitStrategy=Yield
```

After some digging I found out that log4j find `javax.servlet.Servlet` class and sets `Constants.IS_WEB_APP` property to `true` so my `-Dlog4j2.enable.threadlocals=true` is actually set to false then, and because of that it's using `ParameterizedMessageFactory` instead of `ReusableMessageFactory` which lead to calling `toString`, I tried to run it in simple project with same configuration but without `javax.servlet.Servlet` it works fine.

So the question is why it has such behaviour that it's calling `toString()` instead of `formatTo()`? Why it depend from is it web app or not? I understand the problems that webapp threadlocals could cause, but I don't understand why the `ParameterizedMessageFactory` doesn't then use this `formatTo` too. Also if I am logging using this  `StringBuilderFormattable` only from the core thread, is it safe to set `log4j2.is.webapp` to `false`?

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. "toString" is being called instead of "formatTo". Have you found any workaround for this issue?